# angular.js:12759 : OPTIONS 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http-post

i m implementing http request with angular js
but when i m passing the http request keep getting Error code 405 Method not allowed due to json POST form data i m using the header application/json

```
 var data_add_cart = {
        service_type : "1",
        product_details : product_array,
        edit_main_id : "0",
        edit_sub_id : "0", 
        api_key: "iZXFJIAFaLVWDx3qmpXuXRnCEsjAU6DZNwt6bEzONAHk4RoRWkyjutho7PQgZlFSYFqEZuspMzubzz0Lg8iXIIQ/t+oyheL4HxGouRJlz8o=",
        log : "",
        language_code: "en",
        branch_id: "1",
        device_type: "android",
        lat : "",
        device_token: "ex7n_U-pwlQ:APA91bGwFupIdjXEJqs4ZtdRwXLPPopDqwIU0gOH5n38ZPFEROk8WdAPQMsBxPLRd_3d8J3qIrUqUp8mEEvUjapCj7LVEOPO3kDt1lGT6r9L1C6VntoYuwbZnstfOSaZxeFXnibJXWKj",
        customer_id: "0",
        device_id: "38fd1dae4605918e",
        app_unique_token : "274AD23D-6F62-4102-A1A9-EAECB5B0491E-android-"+$.now(),
    };

             console.log(JSON.stringify(data_add_cart));
             $http.post('http://URLHERE/api/addtocart/', $httpParamSerializerJQLike(JSON.stringify(data_add_cart)), {
                        headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                'Accept': 'application/Json'
                        }
                })
```

i have made changes on .NET(API) side also.but didn't got the appropriate result

i have Enabled CORS , also added all the method on web config which is **GET** , **POST** , **HEAD** , **PUT** , **OPTION** but still getting  the same error

Following errors i am getting

```
-> angular.js:12759 OPTIONS http://URLHERE/api/add_to_cart 405 (Method Not Allowed)

-> Failed to load http://URLHERE/api/add_to_cart: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Answer (score -2):

$http({
  'url': 'http://URLHERE/api/addtocart/',
  'data': data_add_cart,
  'Method': 'POST', headers: headers })